# OpenShift with broken links

Tags: openshift, hostname, forwarding

I've an OpenShift installation.
From the installation environment, I can reach it via
https://console.pat.net.priv:8443
the machines name is "pat".
If I try to reach the openshift installation from a foreign machine
the side can't be reached.
If I call https://pat.net.priv:8443 I'll be rerouted to https://console.pat.net.priv:8443.
Here the problem starts;
https://pat.net.priv:8443/login?....
opens the login but returns to an 
https://console.pat.net.priv:8443/console/oauth?code=...
link. The Problem is https://console.pat. ... can't be resolved?

Can someone help me? I need detailed instructions on how to do.